# Is it possible for a custom post type and sub pages of a page with the same slug as the custom post type to share a slug?

Tags: permalinks, pages

Sorry if my question sounds a bit confusing. So I have a page "About" and currently, I also have a Custom post type "Our Team".

I've set all the posts under the "Our Team" post type to have the URL as "/about/[post-title]"

Right now, both the page About and all the posts under /about/[post-title] are working perfectly but my page About also has a lot of pages under it and the urls are all

- /about/board
- /about/team
- /about/mission

and after flushing the permalinks, all are now giving me a 404 not found :( All of the subpages under About can't be viewed anymore.

This is my custom post type code:

```
/**
 * Our Team CPT
 */
$labels = array(
    'name'               => 'Our Team',
    'singular_name'      => 'Team',
    'menu_name'          => 'Our Team',
    'add_new'            => 'Add Team',
    'add_new_item'       => 'Add New Team',
    'new_item'           => 'New Team',
    'edit_item'          => 'Edit Person',
    'view_item'          => 'View Team',
    'all_items'          => 'View Team',
    'search_items'       => 'Search the Team',
    'not_found'          => 'No Team Found',
    'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No People found in Trash.', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
);

$args = array(
    'labels'            => $labels,
    'description'       => '',
    'public'            => true,
    'show_ui'           => true,
    'show_in_menu'      => true,
    'capability_type'   => 'page',
    'map_meta_cap'      => true,
    'hierarchical'      => false,
    'has_archive'       => false,
    'rewrite'           => array('slug' => 'about', 'with_front' => true, 'hierarchical' => false),
    'query_var'         => true,
    'supports'          => array('title','editor','page-attributes','post-formats'),
    'taxonomies'        => array('team_member_categories')
);
register_post_type( 'Team', $args );
```

What am I doing wrong?